# Sort associative array with attributes using javaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I have this associative array :

```
Arr =  {
     "ID1":{"Attr1":"b","Attr2":"5"},
     "ID2":{"Attr1":"d","Attr2":"2"},
     "ID3":{"Attr1":"h","Attr2":"8"}
     }
```

and I want to sort it with the attribute 2 by numbers and not the ID in descending Order to obtain this result :

```
Arr =  { 
     "ID3":{"Attr1":"h","Attr2":"8"}
     "ID1":{"Attr1":"b","Attr2":"5"},
     "ID2":{"Attr1":"d","Attr2":"2"},
     }
```

If this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object.keys( Arr ).sort(function( a, b ) {
    return +Arr[ b ].Attr2 - +Arr[ a ].Attr2;
}).forEach(function( key ) { 
    console.log( key );
});
```

By invoking `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.sort`, you can at least sort the *keys* of any object. With that, you can access those *key / value* pairs in order.

The output of the above snippet is

```
ID3
ID1
ID2
```

Comment: I think you meant `return Arr[a].Attr2 - Arr[b].Attr2`

Comment: actually it is `Arr[b].Attr2 - Arr[a].Attr2`

Comment: My output is the same: ID1, ID2, ID3 nothing is changed.

Comment: $.each(Arr, function(ID) {alert(ID);}); => ID1, ID2, ID3

Comment: Have you tested your code ?

Comment: @SlimMils: works as intended. You can't "store" the keys in an object. There is no order, but you can loop over the sorted keys and by doing that, you obviously access the ordered combination of the object.

Comment: @jAndy : Where is stored the keys ?

Answer (score 2):

Javasript does not have associative arrays - it's an object. And in Javascript, the order of an objects properties aren't guaranteed. So before you can begin to sort anything, you will first need to convert your data into an array.

From there, it's just a matter of calling [`sort`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) on the array.